# Horizontal Bullet List

Tags: pdfsharp

Trying to draw a horizontal bullet list in PDFsharp. I've been looking at these examples:

http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=581

[How do you have a bulletted list in migradoc / pdfsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025308/how-do-you-have-a-bulletted-list-in-migradoc-pdfsharp)

These are old answers so I'm not sure if the library has changed. As I currently cant find the **Style** and **ListInfo** classes. What library are they hiding in if they are still there?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vertical bullet lists in the pages you link to are made with MigraDoc.

Add a reference to MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel to your project to use MigraDoc and its bullet lists.

Your question is tagged with PDFsharp. PDFsharp does not support bullet lists. With PDFsharp you can draw any type of text and various graphics anywhere to create a bullet list.

See also:
http://pdfsharp.net/Overview.ashx